# jquery effect attached to $("a") selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hamburger Menu Icon [image: Hamburger Menu Icon]

The fadeOut effect I desire to apply to the blue "overlay" (which first slides down when clicking on the Hamburger Menu icon in the top right corner) does not work on $("a") elements that are attached to actual links, ie the first three links - but it works on the "Specials", "FAQs" and "Contact Us" links-which are not linked to any page at the moment). Can anyone tell me why? Thank you.*/**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#toggleSwitch").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").slideDown(1000);
  });

  $("a").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
  });

}); //endReady
```

```css
  /* Overlay Nav----------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
  #overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1181bd;
    display: none;
  }
  #toggleSwitch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  #overlay li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  #overlay a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="overlay">
  <ul class="ulTopMargin">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="howItWorks.html">LAUNDRY LIMO</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherServices.html">OTHER SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img src="img/menuIcon.png" alt="#" id="toggleSwitch"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mini Mall Laundromat Logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: If the page changes then you cannot do this. If you want, you can ajax in the pages into a div and have `$("a").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $("#somediv").load(this.href);
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
  });`

Comment: Thank you, mplungjan - now i'm going to try to figure out how this works…

Answer (score 2):

There is a possible solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#toggleSwitch").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").slideDown(1000);
  });

  $("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).data("href");
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000, function () { self.location = href; });
  });

}); //endReady
```

```css
  /* Overlay Nav----------------- */

#overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1181bd;
    display: none;
  }
  #toggleSwitch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  #overlay li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  #overlay a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="overlay">
  <ul class="ulTopMargin">
    <li><a href="#" data-href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-href="howItWorks.html">LAUNDRY LIMO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-href="otherServices.html">OTHER SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-href="aboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img src="img/menuIcon.png" alt="#" id="toggleSwitch"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mini Mall Laundromat Logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: You can keep the href but preventDefault is a REALLY good idea in all cases

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just `e.preventDefault();` inside `$("a")` like given below:-

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#toggleSwitch").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").slideDown();
  });

  $("a").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $("#overlay").fadeOut();
  });

}); //endReady
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="overlay">
  <ul class="ulTopMargin">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="howItWorks.html">LAUNDRY LIMO</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherServices.html">OTHER SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6OOd.png" alt="#" id="toggleSwitch"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mini Mall Laundromat Logo" class="logo">
```

Actually there is `$("a")` not working because of this `$("#toggleSwitch")` is parents of anchor tag and there is working parent and prevent to child to work so you need to use `e.preventDefault();` with anchor tag.

Comment: Then the links never load

Answer (score 0):

You should use `e.preventDefault()` which is short for `event.preventDefault()`.

When user clicks on an anchor ( link ) it creates and event and the default behavior of that event is to follow that anchor's `href` attribute.

So by adding `e` or `event` as an attribute to the `click function` you can control the behavior of that event. In your case, using `e.preventDefault()` will, well, prevent the default behavior of the anchor( which is what i mentioned above ). So ignoring it, you are able to pass other behavior to that click event on the anchor, like opening the overlay.

See more here -> [MDN preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#toggleSwitch").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").slideDown(1000);
  });

  $("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
      $("#overlay").fadeOut( "1000", function() {
       console.log(this)
    });
  });

}); //endReady
```

```css
/* Overlay Nav----------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
  #overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1181bd;
    display: none;
  }
  #toggleSwitch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  #overlay li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  #overlay a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="overlay">
  <ul class="ulTopMargin">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="howItWorks.html">LAUNDRY LIMO</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherServices.html">OTHER SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img src="img/menuIcon.png" alt="#" id="toggleSwitch"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mini Mall Laundromat Logo" class="logo">
```

If you want something to happen after the fade out, for example go to the `href` of the link

```js
$("#overlay").fadeOut( "1000", () => {
  // animation finished here
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')
});
```

Also use an `arrow function () => {}` so the context of `this` remains the same and it will refer to the `a` not to the `overlay` which would be default